# c# Tcp listener.... client refused connection

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

I've run in to an interesting scenario.

1. Create a simple Tcp listener.

   ```
   while (true)
   {
        Helper.LogMessage("Waiting for connections..." + _clients.Count);
        var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        ProcessSocket(tcpClient);
   }
   ```
2. ProcessSocket-> work is off loaded onto new thread (thread pool as far as i understand)

   ```
   private void ProcessSocket(TcpClient client)
   {
       //if (socket == null) { break; }
       Task.Run(() => {
           //stuff and things like read the client msg...
           Thread.Sleep(5000);
       });
   }
   ```

Client is giving :
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

{"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [ip address]"}

NativeErrorCode: 10061

Test.... I am trying to simulate bombarding the listener with new connections.

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        int cycles = 210;

        List<int> items = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
            items.Add(i);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            string ch = TestHelper.GetText() + item.ToString();
            Send(ch);
            //Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

    }
```

I would like help in figuring out what exactly is happening... I.e. how can i monitor this...

It happen almost immediately... so it cant running out of threads...

Code work almost as you would expect if you take the thread sleep out...

But I am trying to understand why... this is happening.

**Extra code**

```
private void Send(string message)
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ClientAddress), ClientPort);

        try
        {
            socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
            socket.Send(messageBytes);
            socket.Dispose();
            //socket.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to Host!: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please rethink what you're actually doing and what you try to achieve. You are not 'bombarding' with connections, but sending a bunch of short messages. Important parts of your code is missing in the question, wie cannot see the faulty part.

Comment: I know exactly what I'm doing :-).... please ask a question if you are unsure. I know what the code is doing... I wrote it. What I do not understand... is why the client is rejected... when the work on the listener is told to take some time... i.e. 5 secs. I know this is not real world testing... I'm simulating heavy conditions "bombarding" was just a fun word i used... for killing the server with work. quote "we cannot see the faulty part" i know neither can I..., ie the code works fine-ish without the thread.sleep. hence I think this is more technical...and not a simple programming...issue.

Comment: Where is the code of `Send()`? Are you disconnecting after using the connection?

Comment: @TobiasKnauss I have included the code requested......... i understand you want to check my code...**but** what I'm trying to say.... is it doesn't matter...  you will get the error regardless... but i appreciate you want to check before you will believe me. What i suggest is code up a TCP listener how ever you want (must be able to accept multiple clients...) then make the listener simulate work with thread.sleep (5 secs), NOW... i understand that i must be running into some sorts of limits... but i want to know what limits and how do i measure them. Thx

Comment: @TobiasKnauss update the code... again to simplify it more... so its easier to read.

Comment: How often are clients able to connect? I recommend Sysinternals TCPView to monitor the connections and use a large time interval (`sleep(10000)`) for your test. Also, use HWGroup Hercules as a TCP client or server emulator, it can do both.

Comment: Also, I recommend using `TCPClient` instead of `socket`. Makes work a little easier.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss sorry man i don't think you are following... the point of the test is to kill the server(with known's)... changing sleep would accomplish what? I am using TcpClient.... in fact I have tried both... with the same results..., hense why is said it has nothing to do with how i have written it but more to do with unknown limits. I am looking for someone with advanced Tcp knowledge... who can shed some light. Have you written a tcp listener before?... if so... you'll be able to test it aswell, If not... I don't know if you have enough knowledge to help, but thanks.

Comment: I have written a TCP listener and I am using it with multiple Clients, so: yes. I know you want to kill your server, but without getting connections, you should do the first step before the 2nd and check why the connections fail. Well, my server and clients are working fine, so I didn't have to worry about yours if you don't like

Comment: Have you been able to get a single(!) successful connection so far on this code? I would test he basics first, you haven't written anything about it in your post, so I could only guess. And please, omit your series of dots.... Looks ugly. ;-)

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Sorry maybe i wasn't clear, take the thread.sleep out and it works as one would expect!, could you test this with yours.... i believe you should get similar results. i.e i can get it to make hundreds of successful connections and read the content of the msg but only when the listener takes like no time i.e without a thread.sleep. Hope that clears up the confusion.

Comment: i.e i can get to close to 2000 successful connections in less than 10 secs but its not clear what is happening... when i tell it to say for example make each connection work a little harder.(thread.sleep), my guess is a time out but i can not narrow it down, and i have done as must testing that i can think of.

Comment: That's why I recommended TCPView. It will monitor your connections. You will see if the connections are really closed or if they stay (half-)open. I don't know exactly, but I can imagine that there is a limit of open connections.

Comment: Thanks ill have a look at TCPView and let you know ;-)

Comment: you could also use Wireshark to find out the point of time where connections are not opened any further and what happens then, e.g. the SYN packet is sent but it gets no response or whatever.

Comment: marked down with no reason should be forbbiden

Answer (score 2):

I will try a first answer, although I'm still waiting for your TCPView results:
Have a look at [MSDN Socket.Listen()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.listen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which I am quite sure is also the underlying object of `TCPListener`, as well as of `TCPClient`. The website will tell you

> Listen causes a connection-oriented Socket to listen for incoming connection attempts. The backlog parameter specifies the number of incoming connections that can be queued for acceptance. To determine the maximum number of connections you can specify, retrieve the MaxConnections value. Listen does not block.

So, there is a limit of pending open connections. If there is also a limit of open connections, then you'd just have to add both values to know how far you'll get on your test.
In general, your server needs to be able to handle (and close) connections faster as new ones arrive in order to avoid refuses on client side.
I recommend you add a list of timestamps on your client side, so that you see how fast connections are created and data is sent.

I will update my answer when new info is available. You should update your post as well, so we don't add an endless list of comments.

Comment: It what i thought it would be... with TCPView... really hard to tell anything useful.... too much information at once... do you have tips on how to narrow down...TCPView

Comment: Why is it hard to use the TCPView data? You see all network connections of your computer. You can save a snapshot to file and analyse it.

Comment: because honestly all it shows you is masses!!! of information not what is wrong. Its like getting a print out of data... which will not indicate why you were refused a connection. Needle in a hay stack! and it also depends on exact manual timing to capture maybe something useful. You also wont know unless use analyse every snap shot which could take years and because you don't know what you looking for you will probably missing it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I have also played around with the backlog trying values from 10 to 0 to 1000000 with no measurable difference.

Comment: TCPView shows you the active network connections, nothing else. I suggested its usage to determine the number of connections your software is making and whether they are closed again. If staying open, the you'll of course hit a limit! // for network data monitoring usw wireshark, so you'll see the packets, but also you likely won't see when no new connections are opened, because I think the server response will simply be *missing*.

Comment: @Seabizkit: The backlog parameter is treated very differently on server OSes. I would try running this on an actual Windows Server machine, not a client OS.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks for the input, currently I do not have a server... but I fail to see how... c# code would depend on a server... there would be literally no way for it to tell... i.e. how does it know its a server. PS I am not at all saying your wrong... as i know what you trying to say... but in this case i cannot see how it would influence it. on a side note, I highly suggestion everyone setup similar tests to me and try it yourself... easier to talk about something which we are all seeing. As far as I can tell this will happen with your own code too... as its a limit of some sort...

Comment: @Seabizkit: The C# `Socket` class passes its `backlog` parameter to the WinSock2 API, which is part of the OS, and is implemented differently on Windows server machines.